# How to draw a cross?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have a WPF Control.

I need to draw something like below in wpf control.
On resizing the control, the cross should follow its size? I also have to type the letters as below. I should be able to set foreground and background programmatically, by binding to viewmodel property.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried that's not working? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Steve I don't know how to start it. Should I use a label and control template or style or should I use a polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross itself is straightforward if you use `Path` to draw the lines/arrows.  Use a [`ViewBox`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQytx.png) to scale to the container size:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
        <TextBlock Text="N" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="S" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="E" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="W" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                Data="M 15,50 L 85,50 M 80,45 L 85,50 M 80 55 L 85,50"
                />
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                Data="M 50,15 L 50,85 M 45,80 L 50,85 M 55 80 L 50,85"
                />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Now, you can just wrap the above in a `UserControl`.  This already has properties for Foreground/Background, so it's just a matter of binding to them.  Inside the control, use `RelativeSource` bindings:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Controls.Compass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
          Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Background}">
        <Viewbox>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
                <TextBlock Text="N" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" />
                <TextBlock Text="S" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" />
                <TextBlock Text="E" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" />
                <TextBlock Text="W" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" />
                <Path Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1"
                      Data="M 15,50 L 85,50 M 80,45 L 85,50 M 80 55 L 85,50" />
                <Path Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1"
                      Data="M 50,15 L 50,85 M 45,80 L 50,85 M 55 80 L 50,85" />
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now you can create instances of the control like this (assuming the view-model has `Brush` type properties named "Foreground" and "Background"):

```
<controls:Compass Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>
```

[image: compass screenshot]

Comment: Well McGarnagle, Billy is Dead! That takes me back.

Comment: @McGarnagle Thanks for the solution. It works as is expected. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

See this page on [MSDN for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of how to draw lines. I would guess adding 4 TextBlock objects might get the job done.

You could put the whole thing in a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make scaling very easy.